# MSVC2017 Statically linking SQLite3

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2017, static-linking

I have a Microsoft Visual Code 2017 console application which I want to link statically against sqlite3. I have linked the `sqlite3.lib` file and included the `sqlite3.h` file. However, when I execute the program it still pops-up the message that it is missing `sqlite3.dll`. I thought that sqlite3 would be linked statically, what am I doing wrong?

*Compiling goes without errors*

This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "sqlite3.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "sqlite3.lib")

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
        }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
    }
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;

    rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    if( rc ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 1;
        }
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "create table stuff ( name )", callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "insert into stuff values ('hello')", callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "select * from stuff", callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if(rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You will be linking again the "stub" library that just defines the DLL entry points.  You need the full static build library of SQLite.  Where did you get the download from the official site only has source and DLL for MS Windows http://sqlite.org/download.html  ?

Comment: @RichardCritten, right. I have downloaded both the Source and Precompiled Binaries to generate the `sqlite3.lib` file. So this is not the full static library? Sorry, I'm quite new to static linking, trying to understand it as good as possible. Could you give me some details on how to achieve the static library to link against? Many thanks

Comment: A word of advice -- if SqlLite did not provide, up front, a static library, creating one yourself requires you to do far more than just a simple build.  If there is no such prebuilt library, chances are the authors deemed it either impossible or too much of a task to create such a library.  Definitions have to be changed, preprocessor symbols have to be defined / undefined, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, so it might be possible that the sqlite static library is already distributed with my msvc installation? If so, what files should I be looking for?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren -- The static library must be built with the exact same version of the compiler you're using, use the same runtime library as the version you're using, etc. etc.  I highly doubt, unless the authors spent an inordinate amount of their time, built you static libraries that fit neatly with your compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, so actually I will have to redistribute sqlite.dll with my application?..

Comment: Yes, you will have to distribute sqllite.dll, if the authors allow distribution.  If you really want to build static libraries, you need to get all of the source code, and have guidance and instructions from the authors on how to build the library.  You can't go about this alone unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, oke thanks for your explanation. However, this states that all statically distributed exe's have no SQLite performance or have spend a decade on building the static library? Thats a shame, I would like to only distribute my .exe. I have to store only a very small amount of data in the SQLite DB...

Comment: I believe there are utilities that package the DLL's so that they are "hidden" from the user of your app (they are expanded when your app runs).  Maybe you should consider using something like that (don't know how well they work though).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, right. That's not quite what I'm looking for. Is it possible to store a variable somehow without issuing a (SQLite) DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the `sqlite3.c` file alongside your other `.c` or `.cpp` files.  This is a single large file for the whole thing.  Then it will be statically linked without dealing with `.lib` or `.dll` files.